# Restart python script automatically even when it crashes in Linux

Tags: python, linux, shell, scripting

I have a python program that has to be running all the time. If for some reason it was stopped I want to restart it automatically. I thought of having a cron that will run every n number of seconds and check the program is running. My shell script is looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
CM_COMMAND=`ps aux| grep abc| grep def| grep sudo`
LEN_COMMAND=${#CM_COMMAND}
if[["$LEN_COMMAND" -le "5"]] 
then
    echo "start the python program"
fi
exit
```

When I run this script I am getting the error: `my_prog.sh: line 4: $'if[[118\r -le 5]]\r': command not found'`

What is the alternative of doing this and what is the problem with my script?

Comment: One problem is that when somebody runs 6 arbitrary `sudo` commands matching your `grep`s, your script will not be restarted.

Comment: Does the python process need to be running constantly, or is it enough to invoke it at a certain (higher frequency) interval? How fast does it have to restart to fulfil its purpose?

Comment: `ps aux| grep abc| grep def| grep sudo`      if abc is program_name

Comment: The process has to be running constantly

Comment: It has to be running all the time without any stop. If it stops it needs to be restarted as soon as possible.

Comment: *"what is the problem with my script?"* - That's the thing you should tell us.

Comment: when I execute the script it says `my_prog.sh: line 4: $'if[[118\r -le 5]]\r': command not found`

Comment: Put clarifications in the question. You shouldn't need to read the comments to answer.

Comment: Cool just made it clear

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe this would be more robust?

1) save the PID of your process when you start it with:

```
{your_python_command} & echo $! >>/{some_folder}/your_app.pid
```

2) This script will check and restart if it can't find the PID..

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

PID=`cat /{some_folder}/your_app.pid`

if ! ps -p $PID > /dev/null
then
  rm /{some_folder}/your_app.pid
  {your_python_command} & echo $! >>/{some_folder}/your_app.pid
fi
```

3) To add it to a cronjob:

```
crontab -e
```

choose your text editor and add this row at the end of the file:

```
*/1 * * * * /{your_path}/{your_script_name}
```

exit and save

(this will run the script every minute, check crontab manual to set your exact interval)

Comment: if you put it in a cronjob it will get activated automatically on reboot though the cronjob regardless of where you put the script - is that what you're after?

Answer (score 3):

How about making it a service? A very clean solution, in my opinion.

For more information on how to do it, you can read [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-linux-service-to-start-automatically-after-a-crash-or-reboot-part-1-practical-examples).